# How to convert time string to timestamp

Tags: linux, timestamp, sh, ash

I have the following string "2012-09-04T00:11:20.000Z" I need to convert this string to timestamp with ash shell.

How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this :

```
date -d "2012-09-04T00:11:20.000Z" "+%s"
```

**-d str** : Set time described by str

**%s** : Timestamp format

Comment: I get an error when I executed your command `date: date invalide 2012-09-04T00:11:20.000Z'`

Comment: I used this syntax `date -d "2012-09-04T00:11:20" "+%s"`